# In Bash, is there a way to "grep -r foobar *" except it is everything except the "log" directory?

Tags: bash

the line

```
\ls -1 | grep -v log | xargs grep -r foobar
```

partially works except it will also skip the "blog" directory since it also gets excluded by `grep -v log`.  (the `\ls` above is to make `ls` not do any alias such as `ls -F`)

Answer (score 3):

```
\ls -1 | grep -v ^log$ | xargs grep -r foobar
```

or

```
grep --exclude-dir=log -r foobar *
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name log -prune -o -type f -print0 |xargs -0 grep foobar
```

Comment: great answer.  I think on my system i happen to have `.hg` (mercurial) so it grep for those files as well.  Is there a way to skip those too?

Comment: my first version ignores hidden directorys as well as the --exclude-dir version. To dig into these hidden dirs as well you have to change the wildcard from * to * .*

Comment: @Jian, you can add more directories to skip like `find . -name log -prune -o -name .hg -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep foobar`

Comment: You can ignore all hidden directories by adding a `-name '.??*' -prune -o` into there before the `-type ...` part.

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep has this option:

```
--exclude-dir=DIR
              Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from recursive searches.
```

Comment: I am trying on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and it seems like it is not in the man page.  But I do see it on Ubuntu 10.10.10

Answer (score 0):

with bash, you can use `extglob`

```
shopt -s extglob
grep "foobar" !(log)
```